# How to capture a single frame from iPhone4 camera and use it in other view?

Tags: iphone, multithreading, memory-management, ios4, avfoundation

I am capturing a single frame using

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
```

Now I want to see this image on a different UIViewController which presents,
but it doesn't work. I can display the taken image on the same UIViewController but on the other one it seems to be out of scope.

I tried it this way:

In captureOutput method:

```
CFRetain(sampleBuffer);
[photoView addFoto:sampleBuffer];
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(showPhoto:) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
CFRelease(sampleBuffer);
```

photoView is the other UIViewController

```
- (void) addFoto:(CMSampleBufferRef) ref
{
    UIImage *theImage = imageFromSampleBuffer(ref);
    theImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:CGImageCreateCopy(theImage.CGImage)];
    capturedImages = [NSMutableArray array];
    [capturedImages addObject:theImage];
}

- (void) showPhoto:(UIImage*) bild
{
    [session stopRunning];

    photoView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    [self presentModalViewController:photoView animated:YES];
}
```

and in the viewDidLoad method of the photoView UIViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    foto.image = [capturedImages objectAtIndex:0];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
```

foto is the UIImageView

Why it doesn't work? I am desperate...
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you access capturedImages in your other view controller?

Comment: foto.image = [capturedImages objectAtIndex:0]; in the viewdidload method of the other (photoView) view controller

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void) showPhoto:(UIImage*) bild
{
    [session stopRunning];

    photoView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    [self presentModalViewController:photoView animated:YES];
    photoView.foto.image = (UIImage*)[capturedImages objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

Comment: Thank you it worked! I added photoView.foto.image = (UIImage*)[photoView.capturedImages objectAtIndex:0]; I don't know why but it is working :)

Comment: why I can't access the data from capturedImages in the photoView ViewController ? capturedImages are part of photoView

Comment: New very strange problem...

    photoView.foto.image = (UIImage*)[capturedImages objectAtIndex:0];

this line as written above works.

Now I want to display 3 Frames.
I am adding 3 frames with the addFoto method, then i am using the same code for the other 2 Pictures. But only the first works... The strange thing is if the first is

    photoView.foto2.image = (UIImage*)[photoView.capturedImages objectAtIndex:1];

then this one works... So all 3 pictures seem to be correctly in photoView.capturedImages but after the first access the other 2 doesn't work anymore...